# Find 10 commuting $2\times 2$ matrices of the same order

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that there exists 10 distinct real $2\times 2$ matrices which are pairwise commuting and all of the same finite order.

Here, the order of matrix A is the smallest integer $k > 0$ such that $A^k = I.$  Also by 'pairwise commuting', I mean that if $\{A_1, \cdots, A_{10}\}$ are the ten matrices, then $A_i A_j = A_j A_i$ for any $i,j = 1,2,\cdots, 10$ and $i\neq j.$

Linear algebra is not my forte yet, I haven't got a clue where to begin.  The matrices commute so they all have the same eigenvectors... so letting $A_1$ be a matrix of just these eigenvectors, $A_2 = A_1 + I$ would have the same eigenvectors, thus $A_2A_1 = A_1A_2.$  However I am not sure how to deal with making them the same order.

Comment: All you need is one single matrix of finite order $n$ with $\varphi(n) \geq 10$.

Comment: @MooS, what do you mean by $\varphi$ in this context?

Comment: Euler's totient function

Comment: @MooS, thanks. $\;\!$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First Hint.** Define $$R(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $R(\theta)$ represents the linear transform that rotates vectors counter-clockwise by an angle $\theta$.

**Second Hint.** $11$ is prime.

Comment: This is a cool question, by the way.

Comment: Jeez I'm surprised at the simplicity of the answer.  Thanks!